# Error while doing multiple select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do a mulitple select so I have two output columns num1 and num2 .  I have to get the num for the begindate and the finishdate.
e.g  In table 1, the begindate is 02-01-2017. From table 2, we can see that 02-01-2017 falls within 01-01-2017 and 01-02-2017. Therefore, the output for beginnum will be 1.

Table 1:

```
begindate finishdate  
02-01-2017 03-01-2017  
05-02-2017 05-02-2017
```

Table 2:

```
num startdate enddate
 1 01-01-2017 01-02-2017  
 2 01-02-2017 01-03-2017
```

Output Intended:

```
beginnum  
1  
2  
finishnum  
1  
2
```

I have an error while doing this :

```
SELECT(
SELECT num FROM table1 left outer join table2 
ON 
table1.begindate > table2.startdate 
AND 
table1.begindate <=  table2.enddate) AS beginnum,

(SELECT num from table1 left outer join table2 
ON 
table1.finishdate> table2.startdate 
AND
table1.finishdate <=  table2.enddate) AS finishnum
```

I got this error:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

Please help.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The error in your question is obvious.  Your intention is not.

Comment: Hello I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.num
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.begindate > t2.startdate and 
        t1.begindate <= t2.enddate;
```

I'm not sure exactly how your date arithmetic works, why you using only the `begindate` column from `t1` or whether the comparisons are strict inequalities.  But I think that is the idea you want.

Comment: Hello. I would need to include the finishdate column from t1 as well. beginnum is for begindate and finishnum is for finishdate. I have included the output intended.

Comment: The condition did not include the finishdate